# App goes back to login page after google sign in (Flutter+firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-authentication

I'm new to flutter and am following a tutorial on yt .
The issue is that after i click the login button I am prompted to login using google but then it does not route to the home page after logging in and stays on the login page .

This is the error i got :

```
W/tions.notes_ap(31551): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ActivityThread(31551): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@a7ff7e3
W/tions.notes_ap(31551): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/tions.notes_ap(31551): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/tions.notes_ap(31551): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/System  (31551): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System  (31551): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth(31551): Notifying id token listeners about user ( A786R9LAtCasjljXQm6RbApJD2R2 ).
W/DynamiteModule(31551): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(31551): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(31551): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/tions.notes_ap(31551): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/tions.notes_ap(31551): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/tions.notes_ap(31551): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/tions.notes_ap(31551): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/tions.notes_ap(31551): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/tions.notes_ap(31551): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/tions.notes_ap(31551): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/tions.notes_ap(31551): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/tions.notes_ap(31551): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/Firestore(31551): (23.0.2) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(users/A786R9LAtCasjljXQm6RbApJD2R2 order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
E/flutter (31551): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
E/flutter (31551): #0      MethodChannelDocumentReference.get (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_reference.dart:80:7)
E/flutter (31551): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31551): #1      _JsonDocumentReference.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_reference.dart:143:7)
E/flutter (31551): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31551): 
W/Firestore(31551): (23.0.2) [WatchStream]: (b04eca) Stream closed with status: Status{code=CANCELLED, description=Disconnecting idle stream. Timed out waiting for new targets., cause=null}.
```

These are the dependencies i have on pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.1
  firebase: ^9.0.1
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  firebase_auth: ^2.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.3.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.4
  intl: ^0.17.0
```

This is the code that is executed when the login button is clicked :

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/Pages/home.dart';


GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');


void signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
  try {
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();

    if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken);

      final UserCredential authResult =
      await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

      final User? user = authResult.user;

      var userData = {
        'name': googleSignInAccount.displayName,
        'provider': 'google',
        'photoUrl': googleSignInAccount.photoUrl,
        'email': googleSignInAccount.email,
      };

      users.doc(user!.uid).get().then((doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          // old user
          doc.reference.update(userData);

          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomePage(),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          // new user

          users.doc(user.uid).set(userData);

          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomePage(),
            ),
          );
        }
      });
    }
  } catch (PlatformException) {
    print(PlatformException);
    print("Sign in not successful !");
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code which is executed when the login button is clicked?

Comment: I've edited the question to add the code

Answer (score 0):

According to your Error it seem that your firebase database rules are expired which is read, write : true;

go to you firebase database and click on rules and edit your rules .

set rules in database firebase